# De-compress / De-serialize unknown binary data

Tags: encryption, compression, binary-data

I have some "unknown" binary data that has been compressed, packed or formatted by an old in house application in a way that is unreadable. The old in house application can still work with this data.

Without access to the in house application source code, is there a way we can determine the format of this file so we might be able to decompress it for other uses?

When viewing this file in "less" on a linux machine it looks like this:

```
0>^V<FF><D4>^@<BE>C`^B^Oc^_c^N`^B^Oc^O`^A^O`^B^]c^]c+`^A*`^B+c+`^A;c<c;c9p^C^C<F6>p^A^D<F6>cIcJ`^A;cK`^BIs^D<F7>p^B^C<F7>c9`^A:c<`^A<c=`^B=`^A=c^^c/`^B^^c^^c^\`^B<c+`^B<c^]`^A^_c^OS<80>^X<FE><E1>^@;Cc^P`^C^O`^A^A`^A^P`^A0c1`^BAcR`^Ars    ^Cp^B^K^Cs^K^Cp^A^M^Cp^A^L
^Cs^M^Cs^L^Bp^B^M^Ap^A^L^Bs
^As     ^Bp^B   ^Bs     ^B`^Asp^B^H^Bcr`^Accrcb`^BQcR`^BAcR`^AAcB`^BAcB`^A1c2c!`^A!c^R`^B^QS<80>^R<FF>T<FF><92>C`^B<FE>c^Oc<FE>`^B<F0>c^O`
^A^A`^Cbcb`^Brs       ^Bp^B   ^Bs
^Cs
^Bp^B
```

Are there any tools out there that might be able to run this data through a common set of basic decompression algorithms and output the result of each, so we can sift through the results to see if there is anything useful?

---

Update:

```
:~$ file /tmp/data
/tmp/data: data

:~$ od -x /tmp/test
0000000 01b3 0113 01e0 23f3 0000 0004 2033 03e4
0000020 6970 6e63 6369 d300 8001 003e 0144 2361
0000040 0000 0004 b833 43e5 0260 63f0 60f0 f001
0000060 0260 60f0 0f02 0260 630f 601f 0f02 1f63
0000100 0260 631f 631f 601e 2f01 0160 633d 602e
0000120 4d02 3d63 0160 635b 604c 4b01 0260 634d
0000140 635c 604c 5d02 6d63 0160 635c 606d 5c02
0000160 6d63 0160 635b 605c 5c02 5b63 5d63 0160
0000200 605c 5d02 5d63 6d63 0160 606d 6e01 0160
0000220 635c 636d 605c 5d02 5c63 0160 634c 603d
0000240 3e02 3e63 0160 601f 1f01 0460 6010 f003
0000260 0360 6001 1001 0260 63f0 6310 60f0 1004
0000300 0160 6040 4001 5063 0260 6350 6041 4001
0000320 5163 0160 6340 6040 5102 0160 6340 6351
0000340 6361 6051 5103 6263 6163 0260 6351 6062
0000360 5102 5163 4163 5163 0360 6341 6031 4101
0000400 3163 3163 0160 6341 6041 4102 5163 0160
0000420 6040 4102 4163 3063 0160 6341 6031 3102
0000440 2063 3163 0260 6320 6021 3002 2163 2063
0000460 0260 6311 6010 1001 0160 6001 0105 0160
0000500 6310 6011 1004 1163 1163 1063 0260 6301
0000520 6010 1102 0160 6311 6011 1102 1063 0163
0000540 0260 6011 1101 1163 0260 6311 6010 0101
0000560 1063 0360 60f0 0105 0360 60f0 0102 0163
0000600 f363 0260 6304 60f5 e402 f563 e363 e463
0000620 0260 63e4 60e4 e601 e763 0270 08fd d663
0000640 e663 0360 63d5 60d4 e401 f563 0160 63e5
0000660 70f7 fe02 6308 63e6 60f6 e401 0260 63f4
0000700 60f3 f201 f363 f363 0260 63f4 60f5 f502
0000720 0463 0160 63e5 6004 f301 0160 63f3 6002
0000740 f202 0263 0160 6301 6301 60f0 0102 0160
0000760 6001 f001 0460 60f0 e002 e063 0260 63ef
0001000 60d0 e001 cf63 0160 63c0 60cf c002 bf63
0001020 c063 af63 0360 60b0 cf01 af63 0160 63af
0001040 60af af02 bf63 0160 60af 9f01 9e63 0260
0001060 639f 609e 9e01 9d63 0170 fef8 9e63 0270
0001100 fef8 9e63 0160 639d 709e f802 63fe etc..
```

Comment: What does running file against it say it is?

Comment: Looks more like some kind of binary file. Too few values above 0x80, and no readable header. Too many values below 0x20; could it be some XOR-cypher?

Comment: Could you give us that in hexadecimals? On linux try `od -x myfile.probably.bin`...

Comment: Don't you have the source code of the in-house application?

Comment: Added those two above ^^

No source code for the app :(

Comment: Can you tell more about this "in-house application"? Even if there are tools that can try to apply the decompression algorithms, chances that they help you are quite slim, custom code application most likely would have its own twist on those. On the other hand if you knew what langaguge/platform this app is from, which library it uses, etc, you could have a shot at guessing if it's one of the common formats. Let's face it, no one would re-implement zip, and if something like this is what was used it would be via a library.

Comment: Do you have any idea what kind of data this is supposed to be? Address/telephone database? Images? Textual or binary? Also, look at it from a statistical perspective: How large is the total corpus of data (how many different data files do you have to work with)? What's the smallest file? Largest? What's the average size (mean, median, and mode)? Do their filenames tell you anything? Random strings? Sequential numbers? Meaningful text?

Comment: Why don't you ask the author of the program?